# Select2 accessibility issue on auto generated input field

Tags: accessibility, jquery-select2

I am using a select2 dropdown which dynamically creates an input field to search the options. Is there anyway I can give the aria-label/ explicit label to make this element more accessible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.